# Spring boot with Thymeleaf 3 Beta

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Spring boot does not seem to play well with Thymeleaf 3 beta.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration due to internal class not found. 

This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
```

....

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/resourceresolver/IResourceResolver
```

Any ideas on how I can make it work?

Essentially, I have prebuilt HTML templates which do not really conform to XHTML standards and I want to use this with Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf 2 does not support HTML and even the LEGACYHTML5 mode throws up errors due to angular markup

So, I am stuck with Spring Boot which only uses Thyme2 and no support for Thyme3 but my app would only work with Thyme3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: as of 1.4, Spring Boot support Thymeleaf 3 but version 2 remains the default. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3) for details on how to use Thymeleaf 3.

Spring Boot 1.3 and earlier don't support Thymeleaf 3. You'll need to disable Boot's auto-configuration for Thymeleaf and configure it manually. You can disable an auto-configuration by using the [`exclude` attribute on `@SpringBootApplication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html#exclude()):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: Any idea if spring boot is going to release their beta version with support for thyme 3 beta?

Comment: As it's still in beta, there are no firm plans for Thymeleaf 3 support at the moment. You might like to open a Spring Boot issue so it can be considered for 1.4.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks Andy!

Comment: Any updates on this? Does spring boot currently support Thymeleaf 3? I created a project with spring-boot, I see thymeleaf jars are 2.x but configurer is 3.

Comment: 1.4 supports Thymeleaf 3. See the documentation for more details: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3

Answer (score 8):

This is the correct answer. Here is the class to exclude to make it easier for the next person with this issue:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Does that mean we have to manually configure Thymeleaf like a plain spring application?

Comment: No manual config. You are simply ignoring Spring Boot's automatic configuration for Thymeleaf. I was successful excluding the auto config and implementing a Java based configuration using the migration docs here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html